# SIP: In what cases method ID in Request URI is different form cseq method ID?

Tags: sip, ims

Could some-one explain in what cases, method ID in Request URI is different from cseq header method ID?

Regards,
KNP

Comment: Do you mean the SIP URI  `method` header?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean method name. So 'NO' is the answer. Method name in Cseq must match that in request-uri.

Quoting rfc 3261 -

```
The CSeq header field serves as a way to identify and order transactions. It consists of a sequence number and a method. The method MUST match that of the request.
```

Regards,
Sudhansu